# I broke a promise along with a terrible condition. Will Allah still forgive?

Tags: allah, sin

I am a girl and I am 13 years old.

I made a promise to Allah. I said 'Allah I promise to never sin again. If I do, then you can never forgive me or listen to me'. I broke the promise and I sincerely regret it. I made the same promise again, and broke it. Astaghfirullah I'm such a fool. I wish I never broke the promise, and I wish I was never a bad muslim. I feel like Allah might not forgive me anymore for this promise.

Will Allah still forgive me or am I doomed?
I want to be a good muslim and I really dont want to go to hell.

Answer (score 0):

Asalamualaiakum,

We should never give up hope on the mercy of Allah.
Allah has forgiven the biggest of sinners and we are nothing compared to them.

Despair not of the Mercy of Allah: for Allah forgives all sins: for He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful. Again, God says to the believers in a Hadith Qudsi: "O son of Adam, so long as you call upon Me, and ask of Me, I shall forgive you for what you have done, and I shall not mind.

GIve up hope on Allah is one of the biggest sins in Islam.
So, never give up hope and always strive to get closer to allah.

This video should help you a lot,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p5H-FuVFXM&list=WL&index=1

Please watch this video too.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiFKNwICS8U

Story of a person who killed 99 Persons and then repented.

You are never doomed or destructed.

May Allah Grant You Jannah.

Asalamualaikum Warahmatullahi Wabarakthuhu.